Setting GCC target options (AVX2) for static inline variables with a pragma doesn't work?
I'm using AVX2 instruction to initialize static inline variables in my code. But the following does not compile.
#pragma GCC target("avx2")
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

class A {
public:
    static inline __m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi32(0x80000000);
};

int main() {
    __m256i p = _mm256_setr_epi32(-1, 2, -3, -4, 5, 6, 7, -8);
    p = _mm256_and_si256(p, A::mask);
    int* v = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&p);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        std::cout << (v[i] != 0 ? '-' : '+') << ' ';
}

If I move the static variable inside the main function it compiles successfully. But I can't do it because my actual class is more complicated. It seems like #pragma GCC target isn't affecting this static variable.
I also found that -mavx2 compiler argument compiles the code successfully. But the online judges doesn't accept compiler arguments. Is there any other way of compiling this code without -mavx2

What is __m256i? When post a code, don't remove #include. Also don't make in invalid with ellipses.

Don't use static const __m256i - it doesn't compile efficiently: typically reserving space in .bss and using a runtime constructor to init it (copy from .rodata or in this case hopefully materialize with vpcmpeqd ymm0,ymm0).  If you want to define a mask that's used in multiple functions, use static const uint32_t maskval = -1UL; and use _mm256_set1_epi32(maskval) inside each function that uses it.

@3CxEZiVlQ: I don't think that's a good duplicate.  My old answer there happened not to mention per-function target options via __attribute__ or #pragma, but those are supposed to work: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html .  (I updated my answer on Compiling legacy GCC code with AVX vector warnings to mention that, even though it's not what the question's about.)  IDK if perhaps the pragma doesn't apply to static constructors?

A true [mcve] for this should be tiny, basically just this with #include <immintrin.h> and without the ....  Once that's done we can reopen.  (You can also retitle it to mention static class members if the pragma works like it should for whole functions.)

@PeterCordes That is a good duplicate, your old answer, the second paragraph perfectly answers this question.

I've updated the question.

@3CxEZiVlQ: No, it doesn't, because like I said, that paragraph is only addressing the case where you don't use __attribute__((target("avx2"))) or the equivalent pragma, because that wasn't part of the code in that question.  The OP here has used #pragma GCC target (string, …) as documented: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html

@PeterCordes As you see in the question, the pragma does not work.

@PeterCordes I have many functions in my actual class so defining mask in each function will result in huge code duplication

But the online judges doesn't accept compiler arguments. It's neither supposed to use avx2 instructions.

@3CxEZiVlQ: And the question is why the pragma doesn't work in this case, with a static class member.  That duplicate doesn't answer it at all.  As I mentioned, I just updated it to add that attribute and pragma are supposed to work (and do work for functions, as in https://godbolt.org/z/9nhr1dsfT - at least for GCC but not clang).

@3CxEZiVlQ But it does without static inline variables.

@SoumyadeepDash: You could use the C preprocessor like #define Amask _mm256_set1_epi32(0x80000000) to minimize source duplication.  Or define static const uint32_t mask = 0x80000000; in the class, and in functions use _mm256_and_si256(vec, _mm256_set1_epi32(A::mask)).  Those will both compile efficiently without defeating constant propagation or needing an actual runtime constructor to store to .bss

If you're worried about runtime performance, compilers do coalesce identical constants from separate functions (at least in the same compilation unit, perhaps at link time across object files), so ironically it's better to define the same mask separately as a local variable in 10 functions than to use static const __m256i.

@PeterCordes It does not work even if the static member variable is not inline https://godbolt.org/z/4jPvsKbvP Hence, the old question answers: use -mavx

But it will add overhead because _mm256_set1_epi32() will be invoked each time I call the function

"But the online judges doesn't accept compiler arguments" - Sounds like you are doing "competitive programming". The best advice I can give you is; Stop doing that and instead learn C++ properly and work on real (open source) software instead of that competitive coding crap that just teaches bad habits and skills you cannot actually use in the real world.

@SoumyadeepDash: _mm256_set1_epi32 with a compile-time constant arg will fully optimize away!  Look at the asm: https://godbolt.org/z/MW7G39eE3 - after inlining a small function into a loop, the constant is set up in a register once ahead of the loop, then used like vpand  ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi] where YMM1 holds the constant.

@SoumyadeepDash: Remember that intrinsic functions like _mm256_set1_epi32 are not separately-compiled functions that have to actually get called; they will inline and optimize.  Just like you could write 6*2 inside a loop and the compiler will use 12 instead of re-computing anything inside the loop at run-time.  You'd only have to worry if the arg was a runtime variable, especially one that you know is loop-invariant but which the compiler can't easily prove. (e.g. a non-const global variable in a loop that reads and writes via other pointers that might alias the global.)

@3CxEZiVlQ: Yes, it seems that #pragma doesn't work for static class member (or global) variables.  But that other question doesn't address that at all.  This is a different question.  (And an X-Y problem since the OP mistakenly thinks that static will help with efficiency when ironically it actually hurts due to compilers being bad at handling _mm_set functions as static initializers, not treating them as compile-time constants in that context, only inside functions.)
